# Is anything like wso2 esb studio available for development application and can deploy to wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to know if is there is any separate development studio available for wso2 esb.
If available can you provide me a link where i can download wso2 esb studio for development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/). Please check the [Installation Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Installation), [Quick Start Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Quick+Start+Guide) and [Samples](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Samples).

Please check [Creating ESB Artifacts User Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/Creating+ESB+Artifacts) from  [WSO2 Developer Studio Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS371/WSO2+Developer+Studio+Documentation).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using WSO2 developer studio is one time stop to create different types of artifact projects. There is a separate project type called ESB Config projects which will be useful to your requirement. You can refer the product documentation which Isuru pointed.